# Removing Glued-On Stub Out

Tags: drain, drain-waste-vent, kitchen-sink, pipe-fitting

I am replacing my two-bin sink with a one-bin sink. As a result, the garbage disposal is now resting on the tip/edge of this angle stub out that is glued on to the waste drain.

I was good up to this point with the tools I have to complete the installation. But if this involves sawing off the part that’s glued on, I’m going to give up and call someone to do it for me.

So, my question is, can I remove this *relatively* easily with a mechanism that doesn’t include sawing? Or would I be better off hiring someone to do it for me?

[image: Glued on stub out]

Comment: Could hire someone or go to a store and buy a hand saw for about 10 or 20 dollars.  Those pipes are plastic and easy to cut.

Comment: Can you clarify what your specific objection to sawing is?

Comment: Both crip659@ and brhans@ are right.  I overestimated the effort needed to saw/cut it.  I just did that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I overestimated the effort needed to saw/cut the pipe.  @ecnerwal's answer led me to that notion, although didn't come out and say it.  I'm not sure who would have an objection to sawing but not cutting (sounds like a weird political kink *"...a conscientious sawing objector"*).

Sawed, 90° right-angle, p-trap, done.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to **saw**, but don't mind **cutting**, there are several types of non-saw PVC pipe cutters.

[image: Image from an amazon listing of getuhand cutter, which I've never heard of, but it's just an example.]

There's (IME) no practical way to change that fitting without cutting the pipe. I've had success getting pipe destructively out of fittings with heat, but one reason that's possible is that the fittings don't soften as soon as the pipe does. So I don't think you can take a fitting off a pipe that way.

There appears to be just enough room to cut and add a coupling to the pipe you have (once.)

Depending on the actual drain geometry issue, there may also be an approach that allows you to leave this in place by rotating/extending/adding parts on the inlet side. Sometimes what appears to be the direct route is not the best way to connect a drain, due to limited options in space.